# How do event listeners work with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What the script should do:

- wait for button A to be present in the DOM
- click it when ready
- wait X seconds
- click button B
- wait for button A to be reloaded in the DOM
- click button A
- rinse & repeat

In this case:

```
var counter = 0; 
var aClicked = 0;
var waitTime = 5;


setInterval(function () {  
  // Wait for page (specific button) to load
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if (aClicked === 0) { // Click button A once, then wait
      $('#buttonA').click(function () { 
              aClicked = 1;
      }); 
    }
  }); 
  counter++
  if (counter === waitTime) {
      aClicked = 0;
      counter = 0;
      $('#buttonB').click(); // <= reloads part of the document 
  }
}, 1000);
```

I need to click button A, wait for some time, then click button B. Clicking button B
reloads parts of the page (including button A) that needs to be clicked again when loaded.

But `$(document).ready()` is async meaning that the counter is going to be incremented regardless whether button A is clicked or not (the flow should be click A and start the counter afterwards (after DOM update)). But the waiting logic cannot be placed in the same ready() handler since the doc is ready (executed) once).

I'm not sure, in `$('#buttonA').click(function () {});` is `function()` executed after the click, or after the effects of the click register in the DOM? To be on the safe side of async, shouldn't it be better to place the `setInterval()` into the `click()` handler? Something like:

```
var aClicked = 0;
var bClicked = 0;
var waitTimeMs = 5000;

// Wait for page (specific button) to load
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (aClicked === 0) {
    // Click button A once, then wait
    $("#buttonA").click(function () {
      aClicked = 1;
      setInterval(function () {
        // Wait waitTimeSecondsFirst
        if (bClicked === 0) {
          bClicked = 1;
          return;
        }
        bClicked = 0;
        if ($("#buttonB")) {
          $("#buttonB").click();
        } else {
          // Kill interval
        }
      }, waitTimeMs);
    });
  }
});
```

Is this fully async?

Comment: What does "fully" async mean? Scratch that. What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Forget about everything you think you know about async vs sync, what document.ready does, etc.. Just explain what you want to happen. Then we can tell you how to make that happen. Worry about sync/async and all the rest of it later.

Comment: Look for a button in a page, click it if present, wait some time, click another button, wait for page to reload, click on first button if ready. Do this a few times.